# Probability CCDF developped to Expectation form for an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

Please, can someone help me to prove this formula?

$$ P\{\,H ≥ k.R^a.(J(R)+N)\,\} = E_R\{\,exp(-k.R^a.N/q). E[ exp(-k.R^a.J(R)/q)|R]\,\}$$

With H is exponential distribution with parameter q.

P is the probability. J(R) is a function of R.

E is the expectation.

I hope that the formula is clear enough.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: First step: For every nonnegative $x$, $$P(H\geqslant x)=e^{-x/q}$$ Second step: For every random variable $X$ independent of $H$, $$P(H\geqslant X)=E(e^{-X/q})$$ Third step (odd, you might have forgotten to explain aspects of the setting): For every measurable functions $u$ and $v$ such that $u(R)v(R)$ is integrable, $$E(u(R)v(R))=E(u(R)E(v(R)\mid R))$$ Re the third step, it seems absurd as stated since $E(v(R)\mid R)=v(R)$ but if $J(R)$ is replaced by $J(R,S)$ for some other random variable $S$ such that $(R,S)$ is independent of $H$, then indeed use $$E(u(R)v(R,S))=E(u(R)E(v(R,S)\mid R))$$

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. It's very helpful :)